# Android: Calling Multiple Activities in a row in a certain order

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Can somebody explain how to call several activities from one activity in a certain order?

Actually I want to call 1st sub-activity (if the corresponding conditional is true), wait for it to finish, then call 2nd sub-activity (also if the conditional allows), also wait for it to finish and so on. In the end the app must go to another activity and close the one from which the sub-activities were called.

The problem is that the app executes all the intents at once, and the activity which is supposed to be called last appears on the screen at first.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(allocated)
        {
            super.onResume();
            if (warEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, War.class);
                warEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (annexEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Annexation.class);
                annexEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (heirEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dynasty.class);
                heirEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (diseaseEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Disease.class);
                diseaseEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if (corruptEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Corruption.class);
                corruptEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            if (catchEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatchCorrupt.class);
                catchEvent = false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Coliseum.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

What I want is to call War, return to the main activity, then call Annexation, and so on, and Coliseum should be called in the end. For some reason, onPause() of the main activity doesn't get called and all intents are executed at once, so Coliseum gets called first instead of War.

Comment: Why don't you use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)?

Comment: How about using `startActivityForResult` and do if-else so you only start one activity at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `startActivityForResult` framework. First declare a key:

```
public static final String KEY_LAST_STARTED_ACTIVITY = "last-started-activty";
```

Then start your first `Activity` (Rethink if `onResume()` is the most ideal place to start an `Activity`. It is called more often than you'd think, so read the docs for that):

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(allocated)
        {
            if (warEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, War.class);
                warEvent = false;
                startActivityForResult(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your `War`  activity, `setResult()` so that in the main `Activity` you can figure out which was the last `Activity` that was started and decide what to start next:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putString(MainActivity.KEY_LAST_STARTED_ACTIVITY, War.class.getSimpleName();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
// finish() immediately or sometime later
```

In your main `Activity`'s `onActivityResult()`, use the result to figure out what to start next:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (data.getStringExtra(KEY_LAST_STARTED_ACTIVITY)) {
        case "War":
            // Last activity that was started was War, start the next one
            if (annexEvent)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Annexation.class);
                annexEvent = false;
                startActivityForResult(intent);
            }
            break;
        // ... Add other cases for other activities

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very useful idea, but I am not sure how to implement it so it could work for every combination of possible activities to be called. What if, for example, `warEvent` is false, and we need to call `Annexation` first? Or `War` was called, but `annexEvent` is false, but some other condition is true and another activity should be called after `War`? Checking every condition in each `case`-statement is not an option.

Comment: You can create a `List` of `Activity`s to be called in order based on any conditions. Then use `startActivityForResult` like above, but also maintain an index variable to keep track of where you are in the list. In `onActivityResult` increment the index and start the next activity. If the Activity order changes while other Activities are being run I think `Fragment`s are the way to go..

Answer (score 0):

Best case for your scenario would be to work with ***startActivityForResult*** as @nash mentioned.

You can simply *start an activity "B"* by calling **startActivityForResult** "A" and further can **finish** that activity by **setting result OK** in activity "B" in that like below

```
Intent in = new Intent ();
            in.putExtra (LATITUDE, lat);
            in.putExtra (LONGITUDE, lng);
            setResult (RESULT_OK, in);
            finish ();
```

Then further receive the finish call in onActivityResult of activity "A" and can then you can apply you BI (business logic). And accordingly, you can do the same with other activities.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be passing a flag accross the new Activities and at the end of each one check for the conditions to met so you can start the new one or go back. You can customize the activities using Intents flags

- http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/passing-data-between-activities-2.html
- https://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

Remember that there's no warranty in Android that whenever you try to launch an Activity through an Intent it's just that, and intent to launch a new Activity; And Android nature is to show one Activity at a time.